# No predefined constructor existing C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have been spending hours on this but I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. 
I have am working with two header files, one is Load.h and one is Source.h.

This is my load.h:

```
#ifndef LOAD_H
#define LOAD_H
#include <string>
#include "Complexnumbersfrompreviousweek.h"
#include "Otherfunctionsfrompreviousweek.h"
#include "Source.h"

    class Load : public Source //I'm doing this to inherit the vs term
    {
    private:
        double load;
        double vload;
        double ApparentP;

    public:

        Load (double, double, double, double);
        double Calcvload (double, double, double, double);
    };
    #endif LOAD_H
```

This is my Source.h:

```
#ifndef SOURCE_H
#define SOURCE_H
#include <string>
#include "Complexnumbersfrompreviousweek.h"
#include "Otherfunctionsfrompreviousweek.h"

class Source {
public:
    double vs;
    Source(double);

    double Ret(double);
};
#endif SOURCE_H
```

And this is my second .cpp file:

```
#include "Line.h"
#include "Load.h"
#include "Source.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

Source::Source(double VoltageS)
{
    VoltageS = vs;
};
double Source::Ret(double vs)
{
    return vs;
}
Load::Load(double VoltageS, double Sl, double Z, double Vl)//Constructor
{
    Z = load;
    Sl = ApparentP;
    Vl = vload;
    VoltageS = vs;
};
```

The error I get is error C2512: 'Source' no predefined appropriate constructor available.

This is what I am doing in my main():

```
Source Sorgente(VoltageS);
Load loadimpedance(VoltageS, Sl, Z, Vl);
```

So basically I am creating the "Sorgente" object using VoltageS as an argument (selected by the user, I didn't put that bit of code in) and I am trying to assign it to Vs in order to use it in the constructor for the Load afterwards...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Load` inherits from `Source`, it has to construct the `Source` base in its constructor:

```
Load::Load(double VoltageS, double Sl, double Z, double Vl)//Constructor
{
```

Since you don't explicitly specify one, the compiler will automatically insert the default:

```
Load::Load(double VoltageS, double Sl, double Z, double Vl)//Constructor
: Source() // implicitly inserted by compiler
{
```

But that constructor doesn't exist - hence the error. To fix this, you need to explicitly call the correct constructor:

```
Load::Load(double VoltageS, double Sl, double Z, double Vl)//Constructor
: Source(VoltageS) // explicitly construct the base
{
```

Unrelatedly, in your `Source` constructor you are assigning the wrong element:

```
Source::Source(double VoltageS)
{
    VoltageS = vs; // you are assigning to the temporary instead of your member
}
```

That should be:

```
Source::Source(double VoltageS)
: vs(VoltageS)
{ }
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your prompt help. I understand what you are trying to say but I don't get what you mean by: "you are assigning to the temporary instead of your member".. Am I not assigning the value VoltageS to that double variable in the Source class? Also I compiled the program and I now get : fatal error LNK1169

Comment: @Paolokiller No, you were assigning the (uninitialized) member vs to the argument VoltageS. And that's a separate question - but probably you declared some function but didn't define it.